# Enable autoplay in video getting from url in webview android

Tags: android, video, webview, autoplay

I am loading a url in webview. The url contains a link to a video. Is there any way to autoplay the video once the url gets loaded in webview?

I tried doing this but this did not work

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Comment: It is a youtube video?

Comment: https://vh-sg-04.bbb-engine.com/playback/presentation/2.3/6327b462be0d10b24ed5434deaf10deed0a627ae-1669933597168

Comment: Not a youtube video